# Why multiple @import does not work in Vue.js project if I want to import more than 1 CSS files?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am working on one project in which I have one component and few child components that require custom CSS files and some extra vendor CSS files. The problem is, I can't use `@import "path/to/css/file.css"` multiple times within the `<style>..</style>` section for my Vue component.

For example, The code given below will work and it will successfully import the css file and apply styles to the elements that uses the selectors mentioned.

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'header-for-admin'
  }
</script>

<style>
  @import "/path/to/css/file.css"
</style>
```

But the next code won't work and it will not even import any css file. All the styling will get broken and I don't know why this is happening. The major issue is, single CSS file included using @import works but I can't use @import more than once as everything will break.

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'header-for-admin'
  }
</script>

<style>
  @import "/path/to/css/file.css"
  @import "/path/to/another/css/file.css"
</style>
```

I am thinking to create a new `main.css` file in which I will use `@import` to import all the CSS files that a tree of the component requires. Is this a good idea?

**SOLVED:** I forgot to put `;` at the end of the `@import` statement. Went with the flow of Javascript. Moral of the story, Never forget to put `;` no matter javascript or CSS or any other language.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any issues with usage of multiple @import rules. Since, its not working for you for some reason, you can try putting all the @imports into one main.css followed by other style rules. Scripts, stylesheets and other external resources require a server communication and affect page performance, so its always better to keep the number of external files as less as possible.

Comment: F*&^! It was an issue with semi-colon! I forgot to put semi-colons at the end of  the @import statement.